# pyodbc - Image from Microsoft SQL Server writing in binary mode error

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, save-image

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious here...

Whenever I try and use pyodbc to convert and save images from a Microsoft SQL Server, I generate files that are not recognised as images files.

Python code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
q = "SELECT top 1 * from reactorA.dbo.ProcessedImageData"
records = cursor.execute(q).fetchall()

for row in records:
    data = row.AnalysedImage

    with open('test.bmp','wb') as f:
         f.write(data)
```

When I open the newly created image file it's just repeating **ÿ** symbols

When I view the record it seems to be in the correct bytes format

> b'\xff\xff\xff .......

Any help on fixing this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code point `0xff` (255) is ÿ when decoded as Latin-1 text, so that checks out. (Valid) BMP files do not start with `0xff`, so that suggests the contents of `AnalysedImage` are already wrong, or it's not being retrieved correctly, or it's not the format you think it is. Try selecting the contents with a client tool (Management Studio if you're on Windows) to match the contents with what's being retrieved to ensure the pyodbc layer is not the problem.

Comment: Well then, that's not a bitmap. Or of it is, not a bitmap in `BMP` format, as those start with `BM`. Check where your data's coming from.